# Application force close error

Tags: android, logcat

When I'm trying to run my application it shows force close error.

But logcat shows nothing. It means, it didn't show any error messages.

What can I do?

Comment: how to avoid this error, and how to run my application

Comment: unless and untill there is some error , it is hard to predict anything , please paste the logcat here , whatever it says , debug the application step by step , an try to find out the point to create the leakage

Comment: Restart eclipse...Window->Show View->Devices Select your device in devices list then u can able to see the error.

Comment: Ohi restarted. logcat shows errors now.

Comment: @user1931166 Post your code.

Comment: Atleast post some code to find what error is??

Comment: @Subburaj: I Like your possesiveness to solve someone's problem. Keep it.

Comment: Thanks  Sahil Mahajan Mj...

Comment: There may be two reason to not show your log, either your device is not connected or, check in DDMS click on ALL Messages(No Filter), will display your log, now put Break point where you get Force close and debug your application step by step, now if you get log please post here. We will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logcat some times doesn't show error messages as the device is disconnected with eclipse.

At that time you can do as follows

- Restart the eclipse

or other wise

- open the `ddms` and in `devices` tab. A list of Package names will be listed there. Click on your current working package name then you can see messages in the logcat.